# How to remove some operation added to a Bulk operation

Tags: mongodb, bulk

Having the following example (from the MongoDB [`Bulk()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) documentation):

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.insert( { item: "abc123", defaultQty: 100, status: "A", points: 100 } );
bulk.insert( { item: "ijk123", defaultQty: 200, status: "A", points: 200 } );
bulk.insert( { item: "mop123", defaultQty: 0, status: "P", points: 0 } );
bulk.execute();
```

I want to remove the 2nd operation (before executing the `Bulk`) without creating the `Bulk` object again.

Can I do that and how? I did not find this in the documentation.

Comment: Once you hace executed the bulk operation you can retrieve the list of operations executed and then remove it, and create a new bulk. But as far as I know is not possible to remove an operation once added into the bulk operation (even before executing).

Answer (score -2):

Just remove it?

Check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.removeOne/)

```
bulk.find( { item: "ijk123" } ).removeOne();
```

Comment: This is not removing the 2nd insert operation. This is adding a new `removeOne` operation as the 4th operation in the `bulk`.